# ansible playbook syntax error when I using variable

Tags: ansible

I got the syntax error when I run the playbook.

> ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.     did not find expected '-'
>   indicator   The error appears to be in
>   '/var/lib/awx/projects/_39__common/Hyper-V_Shutdown_VM.yml': line 8,
>   column 5, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact
>   syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
   - win_shell: |  
    $a = Get-ClusterGroup | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "{{ vm }}" -and $_.State -eq 'Online'}  
    ^ here
```

We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

```
    with_items:  
      - {{ foo }}  
Should be written as:  
    with_items:  
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

My coding.................

```
---
- name: Hyper-V shutdown VM
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

      win_shell: |
        $a = Get-ClusterGroup | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "{{ vm }}" -and $_.State -eq 'Online'}
        $b = $a.OwnerNode
        Stop-VM -Name "{{ vm }}" -ComputerName $b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Hyper-V shutdown VM
    win_shell: |
        $a = Get-ClusterGroup | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "{{ vm }}" -and $_.State -eq 'Online'}
        $b = $a.OwnerNode
        Stop-VM -Name "{{ vm }}" -ComputerName $b
```

Answer (score 1):

The dash '-' is missing in front of the module name. The correct syntax is below

```
  tasks:
    - win_shell:
```

This is the reason for the error

> did not find expected '-' indicator

Comment: sorry. I got another error.
 could not find expected ':'